# Check piped input on empty spaces and forward it

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I want to pipe the output of one command to another script. In this other script I want to check whether the input was empty or just consists of spaces. If this is the case, I'll ignore it. Otherwise, I want all the input to be forwarded to another few commands.

For more clarity, I'll run something like `cat input.txt | ./script.sh` where `input.txt` looks like

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

and `script.sh` currently looks like:

```
read input_text

if [ -z "$input_text" ]
    # ignore emtpy input
    then exit 0
else
    # do something here with the input
fi
```

The problem is that in this scenario, the first line of the input "line 1" is read into the `input_text` variable and therefore not forwarded with the rest of the input (which then solely consists of lines 2 and 3) into the code following after `else`.

**So**, how can I first check whether the input consists of more than just empty spaces and then *forward the whole input* to another command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would mean you want to forward the input as soon as you see a non-blank character.

```
awk -v cmd='otherCommand' '
  forward {print | cmd; next}
  {initial_output = initial_output $0 "\n"}
  NF {printf "%s", initial_output | cmd; forward = 1}'
```

Example:

```
$ printf '%b\n' ' ' '' '\t' | awk -v cmd='echo START; sed "s/.*/<&>/"' '
  forward {print | cmd; next}
  {initial_output = initial_output $0 "\n"}
  NF {printf "%s", initial_output | cmd; forward = 1}'
$ printf '%b\n' ' ' '' '\t' something | awk -v cmd='echo START; sed "s/.*/<&>/"' '
  forward {print | cmd; next}
  {initial_output = initial_output $0 "\n"}
  NF {printf "%s", initial_output | cmd; forward = 1}'
START
< >
<>
<       >
<something>
```

Comment: This looks like it does what I want it to do. Would you provide a short explanation of what's happening there?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
{   tee /dev/fd/3 <&4&:|
    grep -q '[^[:space:]]' &&
    cat - /dev/fd/4 <&3
}   3<<"" 4<&0 | another_few_commands

# cause i dont know how else to end this with a blank line
```

Answer (score -1):

how about using a loop? (this will end on any empty or space-only lines)

```
#!/bin/sh
while read input_text; do
  [ -z "$input_text" ] && break
  # do something with the non-blank input
done
exit 0
```

Comment: It is necessary that the input is forwarded "en block" to the next command, not just line by line. Is there a way accomplish that?

Comment: This strips off whitespace at the beginning and at the end of each line, and also performs some backslash expansion.